# Получить информацию о количестве кнопок подключенной мыши

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Есть какой либо способ узнать информацию про подключенное к компьютеру устройство (в частности количество кнопок мыши) использую язык программирования Python. К сожалению на просторах интернета не смог найти информацию по данному вопросу

Comment: какая ось ??? windows? linux? macos?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/430528/

Comment: @VictorVosMottor windows, нашел решение

Comment: @Интик Получилось через модуль win32api вытянуть данную информацию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование модуля win32api решает данный вопрос

```
import win32api
import win32con

countMouseButtons = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CMOUSEBUTTONS)
print(countMouseButtons)
```